# Mobile : secure (or not) inputs

Tags: android, ios, security, mobile

I don't know about trojan or malware on mobile phones, but I want to know it there is some real case of attacks where the target is: get keyboard (or screen + keyboards) user inputs. There is some way to protect the device from this kind of troubles? I've read that implementing custom keyboards can help to protect your app. How can I increase my app security? Are captchas enough used in combination with a custom keyboard? Any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system protects the user by running applications in their own sand box. Only one application can access/monitor the screen at a time. Now, if you're talking about a jailbroken device, then well, all bets are off.

The general rule is, if someone has physical access to a device, they own it anyway. So if you don't jailbreak a device, and no attacker physically accesses your device, assuming no major vulnerabilities, you're safe from this type of attack.

Answer (score 0):

> is some real case of attacks where the target is: get keyboard (or screen + keyboards) user inputs.

Well, I'm not sure I've seen anything in practice (or none comes to mind at the moment). Android malware usually just asks for too many permissions and the users (or carriers) gives it to them, so there's no need for underhanded tricks.

To make matters worse, [Google recently removed App Ops](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/12/google-removes-vital-privacy-features-android-shortly-after-adding-them), so there's no way to restrict entitlements on those over-permissed apps (unless you root your device and move to a mod like Cyanogenmod).

There is this proof of concept: [TapLogger: Inferring User Inputs On Smartphone Touchscreens Using On-board Motion Sensors](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~szhu/papers/taplogger.pdf).

There's also the built-in diagnostic software that's a malware writer's wet dream. See QXD, or Qualcomm eXtensible Diagnostic Monitor below.

The Secure Elements folks depend upon a [Trusted User Interface](http://www.globalplatform.org/mediaguidetrustedui.asp), and that includes a Trusted Input and Trusted Screen. Secure Elements are those mini programs (like Java applets) that sometimes run on mini-copressors like embedded smart cards and power things like NFC payments, Google wallet, etc.

---

> I've read that implementing custom keyboards can help to protect your app.

I believe the idea here is to randomize the keys per run to avoid recognizable patterns (should surfers), avoid smudges (infer key taps) and tap logging tricks (like in the paper).

---

> Are captchas enough used in combination with a custom keyboard?

I'm not sure how a CAPTCHA would help here. CAPTCHAs are usually used to slow down automated attacks like bots when the threat model identifies the gap. Do you have a particular use case in mind?

---

> Any feedback?

[Trusted Execution Environments](http://www.globalplatform.org/mediaguidetee.asp) and [Trusted User Interface](http://www.globalplatform.org/mediaguidetrustedui.asp) are tough for commodity hardware because nearly everything is shared, from the cpu to the screen to buses. I think its a case that demand is driving it, so something is going to be sold to take advantage of the market.

Also see, for example, [ARM Trust Zones](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/trustzone/index.php).

---

> How can I increase my app security?

1. Don't use a smartphone
2. Buy a Nexus outside of carrier since its will be updated by Google
3. Avoid carrier Android devices that aren't updated
4. Avoid carrier devices with built-in spyware, such as QXD (see below)
5. Remove unneeded software, like racing games that are "OS Required"
6. Don't install apps you don't write yourself
7. Use a well known mod (like Cyanogen) that addresses some of Android's security gaps

---

QXD, or Qualcomm eXtensible Diagnostic Monitor, gets all this from Sprint. Note that its supposed to be diagnostic software, yet its ripping my personal information like confidential information, messages, contacts and calendar. It also gets permission for pay services. Its pre-installed, and I can't disable it or remove it.

[image: Sprint/Qualcomm QXD spyware]